# how to make this template typedef valid in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

I have a code clip like this

```
  map<string, map<string, map<string, float> > >  map_f;
  map<string, map<string, map<string, string> > > map_s;
  map<string, map<string, map<string, double> > > map_d;
```

And I just want to make this code concisely as this:

```
myMap<float>   map_f;
myMap<string>  map_s;
myMap<double>  map_d;
```

So I tried to use `template` and `using` to achieve this:

```
template<type T>
    using myMap = map<string, map<string, map<string, T> > >;
```

However, I got an error as:

```
error: expected expression
template<type T>
```

My question is, how to modify this code and what does this error means?

The code has been shown blow:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  template<typename T>  
    using myMap = map<string, map<string, map<string, T> > >;
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with on `c++ 4.2.1 @ mac osX 10.13.2`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 temp_def_cls.cxx -o main
```

And I got the error:

```
temp_def_cls.cxx:7:3: error: expected expression
  template<typename T> 
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `template<typename T> using myMap = ...` ?

Comment: @songyuanyao It's still not work, is it work in your computer?

Comment: @springcc [Yes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LaGHsm4bEFt2IcDj).

Comment: You just can't do it inside the function. Move it out of the function.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
    using myMap = map<string, map<string, map<string, T> > >;
```

`type` is nothing special in C++. You need the [keyword `typename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter) (or `class` here).

Move that directive out of `main()`. I used GCC 7.2.0 and the message is much clearer:

> ```
> t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> t.cpp:7:3: error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
>    template<typename T>
>    ^
> ```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code in, but the error still the same. I used `g++ -std=c++11 temp_def_cls.cxx -o main` to compile it on `c++ 4.2.1 mac os 10.13`

Comment: Hi, the complete code clip has been added in the question, please check it.